# Converting column values to row and column names

Tags: r

I have a dataset with two columns, x$x0 and x$x1 and below are the values in this dataset x, there are more than 1234876  observations in the datasets because of many duplicate values.

```
x0            x1
----------------
0             1
0             2
1             0
1             3
2             1
2             3
.             .
.             .
.             .
1234876       1230000
```

I want to **create a matrix** using the *unique values in column1 (x$x0*) and *unique values in column2 (x$x1)*. The values in x$x0 will the row names and values  in x$x1 will be the column names.

Then assign a value 1 to the cells where relation exits between x$x0 and x$x1 , the final results should look something like this.....

```
        | 0 1 2 3 .......1230000
--------------------------------
0       |   1 1                |   
1       | 1     1              |
2       |   1   1              |
3       |                      |
.       |                      |
.       |                      |
.       |                      |
1234876 |                      |
--------------------------------
```

Hope this makes sense :(, any advise on how to do this will be very helpful.

Comment: Post reproducible code example (output from `dput(x)`) so we can help you.

Comment: @smci I did dput(x) ....i get a million lines of something like this 180485L, 180485L, 180485L, 180485L, 180485L, 180486L, 180486L, 
180486L, 180486L, 180486L, 180487L, 180487L, 180487L, 180487L, 
180487L, 180488L, 180488L, 180488L, 180488L, 180488L, 180489L, 
180489L, 180489L, 180489L, 180489L, 180490L, 180490L, 180490L,

Comment: @TyroneWilliams you can `dput(x[1:20, ])` to get the first 20 rows of your data which should be good enough.

Comment: @n8sty dput(x[1:20, ])
structure(list(X0 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), X1 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
0L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 15L, 0L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 
67L, 7L)), .Names = c("X0", "X1"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
>

Comment: @TyroneWilliams what does a relation between the two vectors mean?

Comment: @n8sty , the first table at the top,  ....first table, first row, column x$x0 has a value 0 and column x$x1 has a value 1, so this is represented in the matrix n1 as n1[0,1]=1....if that makes sense

Comment: Would just `table(df)` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell what you are asking, but does this work? It should create a data frame with `x0` values as rows and `x1` values as columns. All the observations become NAs but you could put other things in there.

**Edit:** I've updated this based on your changes and using your `dput` output. This now creates a matrix whose row names correspond to `X0` and whose colnames correspond to `X1`.

```
df <- structure(list(X0 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), 
                     X1 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 15L, 0L, 11L, 12L, 
                            13L, 14L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 7L)), 
                .Names = c("X0", "X1"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), 
                class = "data.frame")

library('reshape2')
df_new <- dcast(df, X0 ~ X1, function(x) ifelse(length(x) >= 1, 1, 0))
rownames(df_new) <- df_new$X0
as.matrix(df_new[-1])

#   0 2 3 4 5 7 11 12 13 14 15 63 64 65 66 67
# 0 0 1 1 1 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 1 1 1 0 1 1 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 2 1 0 0 0 0 0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 3 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
# 4 0 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```